# Possíveis problemas com operadores lógico

Tags: php

Olá, gostaria de saber se tem algum problema ou se vai gerar falhas futuras, utilizar o operador "!" dessa maneira:

```
if (!(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))):
echo "<script>alert('O email digitado: ".$email. " não é válido!');</script>";
echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>"; 
exit;
else:
```

em vez da maneira que está no site da W3C:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
   echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```

[W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/filter_validate_email.asp) - No caso eu somente me refiro ao uso do operador "!" na primeira linha e gostaria de saber também junto com o "=== false" se tem problemas essa diferença ou não.

Comment: testei e não há diferença alguma, os dois funcionam bem, testei com zero, false e nulo. Quanto ao futuro só Deus sabe  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe a diferença, mas não sei se exatamente se aplica ao caso apresentado. A diferença entre utilizar `!(condition)` e `condition === false` é que o PHP natualmente considera alguns valores, diferentes de `false`, como falsos. Alguns deles: número zero, array vazio, string vazia.

```
$tests = [0, [], "", false];

foreach ($tests as $condition)
{
  if (!$condition)
  {
    echo "A condição é verdadeira!" . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Executando o teste acima, perceberá que os quatro testes passarão, pois os quatro valores são considerados falsos pelo PHP e, obviamente, fazendo a negação do mesmo com `!`, o teste passa a ser verdadeiro. Porém, ao fazer:

```
$tests = [0, [], "", false];

foreach ($tests as $condition)
{
  if ($condition === false)
  {
    echo "A condição é verdadeira!" . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Apenas o último teste passará (lembrando que o operador `===` verifica se os parâmetros são idênticos, enquanto o `==` verifica a igualdade de valores).

> Utilizar `!(condition)` é o mesmo que fazer `condition == false`, mas completamente diferente de `condition === false`.

Para a função `filter_var` isso é importante porque ao ler a documentação, verá:

```
Valor retornado: Retorna o dado filtrado, ou FALSE se o filtro falhar.
```

Se, de alguma forma, o valor filtrado for considerado falso pelo PHP, mesmo que este seja válido, a sua condição `!(condition)` indicará o valor como inválido enquanto `condition === false` apenas indicará como inválido se o filtro realmente falhar.

Answer (score 0):

O operador `!` ja é basicamente um `=== false`.

Ele faz a operação de por exemplo:

```
if(!isset($varx)){...
```

significaria:

Se a $varx **não estiver** setada...

Ou:

Se a $varx for **exatamente igual** a falso...

Eles surtem o mesmo efeito, não precisando usar os 2 juntos.

E na verdade, no exemplo ele está invertendo a resposta, falando que se o filtro de e-mail errado for falso ele ta certo (ficou confuso mas é isso que ele ta fazendo)

Comment: Na verdade fazer `!(condition)` é o mesmo que `condition == false`. Utilizar o operador `===` muda completamente o resultado.

Comment: Eu perguntei por que era melhor do que ficar com a dúvida, vai que tem algum grande dilema por trás de um "!", mas é bom saber